# How to split a webpage horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I want to split a webpage horizontally, so I can scroll one site while the other one remains still. But I'm having a really hard time trying to get that done. I found the following code from W3CHOOLS, but it's only works vertically.

The HTML:

```
<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">
    <img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar woman">
    <h2>Jane Flex</h2>
    <p>Some text.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">
  <div class="centered">
    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar man">
    <h2>John Doe</h2>
    <p>Some text here too.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
/* Split the screen in half */
.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Control the left side */
.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
}

/* Control the right side */
.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

/* If you want the content centered horizontally and vertically */
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style the image inside the centered container, if needed */
.centered img {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Please, I need help.

Comment: Well, think of it logically; vertical measurements use `left`, `right`, and `width` and horizontal measurements use `top`, `bottom`, and `height`. From that, can you think of a way of making an attempt at repurposing the code?

Comment: Actually I have been trying for myself for two days, without success.  Could you give me a more precise answer, please?  I need to know which part of the code to delete and which one to add.  Thank you

Comment: Perhaps if you could give us a more precise question of where exactly you are having a problem, rather than a work request and some code copied from another site?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a neat trick lately in css vh and vw.
Basically
width: 100vw
height: 100vh

sets the element to 100% of the view height and 100% of the view width.

it sounds like you could use this to your advantage and have 2 divs or elements both with 50vh.

```
<div style="height:50vh">1</div>
<div style="height:50vh">2</div>
```

in theory that will give you 2 divs that each take up half of the height of the view.

then you just need to set overflow-x: scroll or overflow-x: auto to add scrollbars